Flask One Dictory Pyinstaller App on Windows showing internall
I want to build and run a one-directory py installer Flask app on Windows and leverage preview for rendering.  The data should all come from the One directory folder with the app next to it.  When I try to adjust the path to the system, it fails, generating an Internal Server Error by Flask. This is not the case when running it on the command line.
This is my latest attempt at coding it:
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        from os import path
        bundle _dir = path.abspath(path.dirname(file))
        #Only for Windows
        mainapp.root_path = os.path. dirname(sys._MEIPASS) + '\Folder_data'
        webview. create window( Flask, mainapp) • webview. start()

Does anyone have ideas?  Ideally, I would be able to leverage the static and template folders inside of the directory folder, including retrieving images and saving data.

Please provide the error messages and any tracebacks. Also, is your error a SyntaxError? It seems that your code has quite a bit of errors and other problems. Additionally, please provide the entire code, not just a portion, because the currently provided code isn't enough to reproduce the problem (it will run into syntax errors anyway). Please [edit] to add these information and details to improve.

You can solve it with the function you have already defined, just with some changes and make sure you can pass the same filter or functions to all relevant directory lookup, in command line it works as expected because it is not yet distributed in the temporary directories, there are factors that can help us to provide an answer, with the information given you could use this:
import sys
def resource_path(the_one_folder_relative_path):
    """Get real directory where PyInstaller is reading folder from"""
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, the_one_folder_relative_path)

If you could provide more of the function that serves resources from that folder we can provide the way it should be initiated to access those resources and serve them:
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hi!"
@app.route('/onefolder')
def welcome():
    return render_template(resource_path('/onefolder/welcome.html'))  #this will help PyInstaller to make sure the rendering comes from the absolute resource path folder
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

